# Changing values in dataframe iteraring over all rows and multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to change some values in my dataframe iterating over rows. For each row, if there is a 1 in some column I need to change 0 values in other columns to NA.

I have a code that works, but is super slow when using a bigger dataset.

```
data = data.frame(id=c("A","B","C"),V1=c(1,0,0),V2=c(0,0,0),V3=c(1,0,1))
cols = names(data)[2:4]

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(any(data[i,cols]==1)){
    data[i,cols][data[i,cols]==0]=NA
  }
}
```

I have an example data set

```
data
  id V1 V2 V3
1  A  1  0  1
2  B  0  0  0
3  C  0  0  1
```

and the expected (and the actual) result is

```
data
  id V1 V2 V3
1  A  1 NA  1
2  B  0  0  0
3  C NA NA  1
```

How can I write this in a more optimal way?

Comment: Try `i1 <- rowSums(data[-1] == 1) > 0;data[-1][i1,] <- NA^ !data[-1][i1,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-liner can be,

```
data[rowSums(data[-1]) > 0,] <- replace(data[rowSums(data[-1]) > 0,], 
                                        data[rowSums(data[-1]) > 0,] == 0, 
                                        NA)
data
#  id V1 V2 V3
#1  A  1 NA  1
#2  B  0  0  0
#3  C NA NA  1
```

To avoid evaluating the same expression over and over again, we can define it first, i.e.

```
v1 <- rowSums(data[-1]) > 0
data[v1,] <- replace(data[v1,], 
                     data[v1,] == 0, 
                     NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with `dplyr` assuming you want to change values for `V1` and `V2` column based on values in `V3`. We can specify columns for whom we want to change values in `mutate_at` and in `funs` argument specify the condition for which you want to change values.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate_at(vars(V1:V2), funs(replace(., V3 == 1 & . == 0, NA)))

#  id V1 V2 V3
#1  A  1 NA  1
#2  B  0  0  0
#3  C NA NA  1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R`, by creating a logical vector with `rowSums` and then update the numeric columns based on this index

```
i1 <- rowSums(data[-1] == 1) > 0
data[-1][i1,] <- NA^ !data[-1][i1,]
data
#  id V1 V2 V3
#1  A  1 NA  1
#2  B  0  0  0
#3  C NA NA  1
```

---

If the index needs to be based on a single column, say 'V3', change the 'i1' to

```
i1 <- data$V3 == 1
```

and  update the other numeric columns after subsetting the rows with 'i1', create a logical matrix with negation (`!` - returns TRUE for 0 values and all others FALSE).  Then, using `NA^` on logical matrix returns NA for TRUE and 1 for other values.  As there are only binary values, this can be updated

```
data[i1, 2:3] <- NA^!data[i1, 2:3]
```

Comment: What's the meaning of NA^ ?

Comment: @user570271  It is an easier way to replace the TRUE values to NA, ie.. `v1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE); NA^v1`.  In the example 'data', we create a logical matrix with `!data[i1, 2:3]` where TRUE values are 0 and all others FALSE.  `NA^` returns the TRUE to NA and others to 1